Cannot do npm install --force or --legacy-peer-deps when deploying a project to Vercel




I want to deploy my project to Vercel. Although I have a conflict with the libraries I want to deploy, but even though I told Vercel to use npm install --legacy-peer-deps in its settings, it doesn't use this command to deploy. 
I found that when I added the vercel.json file it invalidated these commands how can I tell it to use npm install --legacy-peer-deps when deploying here? 
Some settings can also be seen in the image above.
I googled some stuff and tried changing vercel.json too.

I did the same, except entered npm install --force instead of npm install --legacy-peer-deps in general > settings > project settings > install command.
Had to redeploy and it works for me.
